# why Activity.Id has two leading 0s and trailing 01?

Tags: c#, .net, distributed-tracing

```
using (Activity activity = source.StartActivity("demo"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(activity?.Id);
}
```

the output is something like `00-bbd8c75b04cda7f7fe9ee03b54b2d7ba-72dc8c0dc24fc406-01`

and it always has two leading 0s and trailing 01, what does those two leading 0s and trailing 01 mean?

also the trace id is `bbd8c75b04cda7f7fe9ee03b54b2d7ba`, according to the w3c format, trace-id that is 16 bytes. but isn't that `bbd8c75b04cda7f7fe9ee03b54b2d7ba` 32 bytes since it has 32 characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're using the W3C activity ID format. (See the [`DefaultIdFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity.defaultidformat?view=net-8.0) property for details of that.

The W3C format is documented [here as traceparent](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#traceparent-header). Importantly:

> ```
> value           = version "-" version-format
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Version (version) is 1 byte representing an 8-bit unsigned integer. Version ff is invalid. The current specification assumes the version is set to 00.
>
> ...
>
> trace-flags An 8-bit field that controls tracing flags such as sampling, trace level, etc. [...] The current version of this specification (00) only supports a single flag called `sampled`. When set, the least significant bit (right-most), denotes that the caller may have recorded trace data.

So basically the `00` is the version, and `01` is the trace flag, meaning "sampled".

The trace ID is 32 *characters* because it's hex-encoded binary data - it's only 16 *bytes*. (Just like the version number is a single byte, encoded as two hex digits.)